# Overscan, Ubuntu 12.04, Nvidia driver

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, display, display-resolution

I know there are many questions about overscan around but I cant seem to find a working solution. I know the cause of this is the Nvidia driver, as I have no problems with the default driver, so I want to ask if any one has fixed overscan on 12.04 with nvidia.

PS Don't say change in nvidia-settings it was removed.

EDIT - After playing with settings I noticed my 16:9 tv has overscan on all 16:9 resolutions but not on 4:3 resolutions, hoping maybe this will help find a fix.

Comment: Are you sure the overscan is a result of your driver/GPU? I haven't seen overscan in any way except for analog TV-out using Nvidia graphic cards in Linux/Ubuntu. Can you verify it's not your TV that's causing all this?

Comment: Yes I only get overscan with the nvidia driver if I un-install it it goes away but the picture is fuzzy with the nouveau driver also I dont get this with windows @ 1080p or my xbox @ 1080p I dont know what else is causing it. There are no overscan options on my TV

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed this with this code

```
sudo nvidia-settings --assign CurrentMetaMode="DFP-1: 1920x1080 {ViewPortOut=1840x1040+40+20, ViewPortIn=1920x1080 }"
```

You can edit veiw port out to match your tv while the numbers after the plus sings will center the screen.

Hope this is useful to someone